# ClickOnce App in Windows 10 using Task Scheduler not working

Tags: windows-10, task-scheduler, clickonce

I have Click-Once app (setup.exe) which I run using Task Scheduler. But on Windows 10 when I run it, its just came and disappear without showing any error. Nothing in Event Viewer. But when I run it by double clicking the setup.exe on Windows 10 then it works.